# Show that $\int_{-a}^{a} f(x) \ dx = \int_{0}^{a} [f(-x)+f(x)] \ dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

**Question :**

Given a constant $a>0$, show that $\int_{-a}^{a} f(x) \ dx = \int_{0}^{a} [f(-x)+f(x)] \ dx$ and hence, evaluate $\int_{-1}^{1} ln(x+\sqrt{1+x^2}) \ dx$.

---

I just follow the definite integrateion rules and tried the following.
[image]
Why is there a negative sign (-) in front of $f(-x)$?

**Thank you for your help.** =]

Comment: If you change the order of integration period, then the sign of the  integral changes.

Comment: Notice your integral is equal to $$\int_{-1}^{1} \ln(x + \sqrt{1+x^2} )dx = \int_{-1}^{1} \sinh^{-1}(x) dx = 0$$

Comment: Try doing a $y = -x$ substitution at the step where you made the big box.  You'll get $dy = -dx$.  Your statement $ = \int_{a}^0 f(-x) dx + ... $ doesn't take into account the sign change on the differential $dx$.  You should get $ = \int_{a}^0 f(-y) \cdot -dy + ...$

Answer (score 0):

you are using $$\int_a^bf(x)dx = - \int_b^af(x)dx$$